# Unable to add assembly reference (dll) to AWS Lambda function project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am developing a AWS lambda function project in .NET. But the problem is I cannot add the assembly reference to the project like other project. I want to use System.Drawing ddl, Image and Bitmap classes in my project. See the screenshot below:

[image]

The above screenshot does not include the option to choose assemblies. This is another screenshot when I add the reference to the different project.

[image]

That adding assemblies option is missing only on the AWS Lambda project. Is it possible to add assembly file to the AWS Lambda project, and if so, how?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dotnet-programming-model.html Based on the information, Amazon Lambda only supports .NET Core model (the project in VS also shows that). If you don't know what is .NET Core yet, learn it first. `System.Drawing` is only in Windows Compatibility Pack, so I don't think you can use it on AWS.